# ORA-01122: database file 5 failed verification check

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, recovery, datafile

Oracle version: 11g r2
OS: win server 2008

```
SQL> alter database open;  
  alter database open  
  *
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-01122: database file 5 failed verification check
>   ORA-01110: data file 5: '[file_path]'
>   ORA-01210: data file header is media corrupt

```
  SQL> alter database datafile '[file_path]' offline;  
  alter database datafile '[file_path]' offline  
  *
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-01145: offline immediate disallowed unless media recovery enabled

```
  SQL> archive log list;  
  Database log mode              No Archive Mode  
  Automatic archival             Disabled  
  Archive destination            USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST  
  Oldest online log sequence     8231  
  Current log sequence           8235  

  SQL> shutdown immediate;  
  ORA-01109: database not open  

  Database dismounted.  
  ORACLE instance shut down.  
  SQL> startup mount;  
  ORACLE instance started.  

  Total System Global Area 2.7392E+10 bytes  
  Fixed Size                  2188768 bytes  
  Variable Size            1.5032E+10 bytes  
  Database Buffers         1.2348E+10 bytes  
  Redo Buffers                9183232 bytes  
  Database mounted.  

  SQL> recover database;
```

> ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
>    ORA-01110: data file 5: '[file_path]'
>    ORA-01122: database file 5 failed verification check
>    ORA-01110: data file 5: '[file_path]'
>    ORA-01210: data file header is media corrupt

Comment: yes, but that's not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put the datafiles in Offline when your DB is in No Archive Log mode.

So below are the steps to recover the database considering current situation :

1. `Shutdown immediate;`
2. `startup nomount;`
3. Recreate the control file using backup trace. :

   alter database backup controlfile to trace as '$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/control_new.sql';

Now make changes in the created control_new.sql:

```
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "db_name" RESETLOGS ARCHIVELOG  
   MAXLOGFILES 16  
   MAXLOGMEMBERS 3  
   MAXDATAFILES 100  
   MAXINSTANCES 8  
   MAXLOGHISTORY 2921  
 LOGFILE  
  GROUP 1 '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db_name/redo1.log' SIZE 400M,  
  GROUP 2 '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db_name/redo2.log' SIZE 400M,  
  GROUP 3 '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db_name/redo3.log' SIZE 400M,  
  GROUP 4 '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db_name/redo4.log' SIZE 400M,  
  GROUP 5 '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db_name/redo5.log' SIZE 400M,  
  GROUP 6 '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db_name/redo6.log' SIZE 400M  
 -- STANDBY LOGFILE  
 DATAFILE  
  '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db_name/system01.dbf',  
 ...  
  '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/db_name/FCJ_DATA_TS_13.dbf'  
 CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8;
```

4. RUn the file in SQL prompt :

   @$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/control_new.sql

5.Mount the database :

```
alter database mount;
```

6. Recover database using control file:

   Recover database using backup control file until cancel;
7. Now open the database :
   `alter database open;`

Comment: http://ulfet.blogspot.in/2014/12/ora-01122-database-file-22-failed.html for reference.

Comment: after following the same I got a data dictionary mismatch error:
ORA-01173: data dictionary indicates missing data file from system tablespace